# Querying S3 Text files using Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I created a database and the table on Athena, to point to an S3 bucket, where I have the log files created using the UNLOAD command on redshift database. Files have a default delimiter as pipe (|) for the columns.

while creating the table using the Athena interface, I used the  **field terminator** as pipe (|) , collection and map key terminator as default. Here is the DDL statement.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS testdb.worktable (
field1 string,
field2 string,
field3 int,
field4 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '|',
  'field.delim' = '|',  
  'collection.delim' = 'undefined',
  'mapkey.delim' = 'undefined',
) LOCATION 's3://bucket_location'
TBLPROPERTIES ('has_encrypted_data'='false');
```

Problem : 
Most of the rows are correctly aligned to the fields mentioned as columns (delimited by pipe |) But when there are spaces in a particular field say for example a space under field2 column, data shifts to the right, meaning **field3** column data is showing up under field4 column

Could someone help me out fix this error ? Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of a line in a CSV file where this happened?  I am experimenting with quote characters, spaces, and line endings and can't reproduce the error.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for asking this question .... the problem was with one of the data in certain columns. It had a pipe (|) in the data that ultimately created an additional column.